# How to play back multiple videos, stopping after each one?

Tags: video, vlc, totem

I want to watch a number of trailers and make notes inbetween each one. So, instead having them play one after the other without stopping, I want each one to automatically stop once it's done, and then I'll hit a key to play the next one in the playlist.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In **Movie Player** (Totem), I could not find a preference or plugin to achieve this.

In **VLC Media Player**:

- Select Tools > Preferences
- Select the Interface tab (default tab)
- At the bottom of the Interface options, in the Playlist section, tick "Pause on the last frame of a video"
- Click Save
- Start playing the first video
- It will pause once it reaches the end
- To move on to the next video, hit `n` (next).
- If you need to go back, hit `p` (previous).

Comment: In VLC 2.2.1: go to Preferences, press Show all, then check Playlist > Play and pause.